# React-native webview is not working as it is supposed to

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use web view this way

```
 <WebView
          source={{
            html: `<p>123</p>`,
          }}
```

But it is not displaying anything,any suggestions please?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/webview Seems to have been deprecated.

Comment: I followed the instructions of react-native-webview as it is said in the official docs but still did not work

Answer (score 1):

[Minimal example with inline HTML:](https://reactnative.dev/docs/webview)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

class MyInlineWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: '<h1>Hello world</h1>' }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```